# Where can I find Andre's "Cinq exposés sur la désingularisation"?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra

Many expositions of Popescu's desingularization theorem indicate that an other proof of this theorem can be found in 
"Cinq  exposés  sur  la  désingularisation" by M. Andre, Ecole Polytechnique Federale de Lausanne, 1992.

> > Where can I find a copy of Andre's manuscript ? Is there any other place where I can find an exposition of Andre's proof ?

Comment: It is a handwritten exposition of Popescu's proof, containing some clarifications and simplifications from the original papers by Popescu, but the proof is the same. Swan's exposition "Néron-Popescu desingularization" incorporates some of these  simplifications (and other ones by Ogoma) and is more readable. The only proof somewhat different from Popescu's original proof is the one given by Spivakovsky.